# Visual Studio 2010 compile error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error when I compile the release of my web application. The project ran fine previously on another machine the hard drive went out on. So I am thinking there is a problem with the configuration. I did some research and it made note of a Web Deploy issue but I am unable to verify what version was in use on the past machine.

Here is the error:

> The "IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidCastException:
>   [A]Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions cannot be cast
>   to [B]Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions. Type A
>   originates from 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Deployment\9.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=7.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Deployment\7.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll'.
>   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ArchiveElementHelper.get_ProviderContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.d__9.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded.CheckMSDeployDumpContainIisSetting(DeploymentObject
>   deploymentObject, String& iisMSDeployProviderName)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded.Execute() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()     0   0   PKL_QMW

Comment: Check the included dlls of the project. It seems to be referencing two different versions of Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](http://forums.iis.net/t/1175754.aspx) this can happen if you install the Web Deployment package without the UI Components.

Try going into add remove programs and doing a Change install on 'Microsoft Web Deploy' and ensure that the UI components are selected to install.